# Why does an embedded form not respond to arrow keys?

Tags: forms, delphi, plugins

I am building a simple plugin framework in Delphi (XE) where the plugins are forms than can be optionally embedded into a TabSheet on a main application. There are examples on the web that explain how to do the embedding, for example: http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips2005/a/bltip0305_5.htm. I have tried this myself and it appears successful. However I find that if I put a TMemo on the embedded form, the arrow keys do not work on the embedded TMemo, ie the cursor on the TMemo will not move. Other keys such as backspace, delete, Ctrl-V etc and alphanumeric keys work as expected (The TAB will not traverse the controls in the embedded form either). A TMemo on the main application works fine. Any idea why the TMemo in the embedded form will not respond to the arrow keys?

Comment: Are you aware of existing plugin frameworks, such as the JVCL's JvPlugin?

Comment: Yes I am aware of JvPlugin, the problem is that there is very little documentation for it so I've not figured out how to use it, plus I would like a plugin system where plugins can use other plugins, does JvPlugin support that kind if functionality?

Comment: Update: I built a very simple example without the plugin system and in this case the TMemo does respond to arrow keys (The example shown in the url in the question does in fact work correctly). The problem therefore lies with the plugin system I have built which is a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with the plugin system I build (which remains to be identified) not with the embedding itself.

Answer (score 0):

I in counter the same way before and i use the Form.Preview := True to inherit the key activity to make it global. try to see [this example](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/delphikylix/256661/257441/re-tformkeypreview--true-and-handle-it-form-global/?S=B10000) it be useful for you.

Comment: I thought of that too but it didn't help. The effect also applies to TEdit controls so it must be a general problem with receiving arrow key messages.